# Trouble installing TMV library

Tags: failed-installation, galsim

I am currently attempting to install the necessary software to run the GalSim, including the TMV libraries. I am currently in the process of following the instructions here to install the software on Windows 7: [GalSim Installation](https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

When I run scons SHARED=false install, it makes it a long way through the process before the following message appears and the installation fails:

```
scons: Building targets ...
rm -f share\tmv-link; echo -ltmv > share\tmv-link
rm: unknown option -- l
Try `rm --help' for more information.
scons: *** [share\tmv-link] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I am rather inexperienced and have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the installation instructions that you linked to: "System requirements: GalSim currently only supports Linux and Mac OSX."

I don't think any of the developers use Windows, but you could certainly [open an issue](https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/issues) requesting that Windows be added to the list of supported systems.